# Internet issue after upgrading os

Tags: networking

I have upgraded ubuntu from 20.04 to 21.04. I have successfully connected the laptop to WiFi but I am not able to use the internet.
Tried restarting network manager
Updated the resolv.conf file.

Please guys some one can help me?
Thank you!

Comment: How did you upgrade? There is no way to directly upgrade 20.04 to 21.04.

Comment: I edited the release upgrades file and the executeed the  sudo do-release-upgrade command.

Comment: This is not a supported way of upgrading. It is expected that it goes wrong.